# About CRS Sparse Matrix storage

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix

Hello i understand how CRS sparse Matrix works but i have a problem : what happens if a row is null (filled only with 0's) ? For example let the 5th row be null, what shall row_ptr(5) contain ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The row pointer value will be duplicated, i.e. the row pointer will look like `[1, 3, 3, 5]`. This makes a lot of sense if you always think of the row pointer telling you how many non-zero entries there have been before the row with the index you're looking at.

By the way: even more interesting is what will happen if the last column(s) of a matrix will be empty. The CRS has no way to catch this scenario, which means that the number of columns is an *additional* information that cannot be encoded in the three arrays used in CRS.

Answer (score 1):

When a last row is zero we also double value. For example, last row number is 10, then a row index array contains [...., 11, 11]